# How to change the "vid" in a field content_taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I would change the vid in this code, I tried to replace it but not to change how do you make it?

```
 $fields[] = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_galerie_type',
    'type_name' => 'rf_galerie',
    'display_settings' => array(
      'weight' => '2',
      'parent' => 'group_galerie_donnees',
      'label' => array(
        'format' => 'above',
      ),
      'teaser' => array(
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => array(
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      '4' => array(
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => array(
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'widget_active' => '1',
    'type' => 'content_taxonomy',
    'required' => '0',
    'multiple' => '0',
    'module' => 'content_taxonomy',
    'active' => '1',
    'save_term_node' => 1,
    'vid' => '60',
    'parent' => '0',
    'parent_php_code' => '',
    'depth' => '',
    'widget' => array(
      'group_parent' => '0',
      'show_depth' => 1,
      'default_value' => array(
        '0' => array(
          'value' => '',
        ),
      ),
      'default_value_php' => NULL,
      'label' => 'Type',
      'weight' => '2',
      'description' => '',
      'type' => 'content_taxonomy_select',
      'module' => 'content_taxonomy_options',
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is quite simple.

First, change in the type of content vocabulary.

Then you need is to add features and the fields in the **.info** module configuration managing content type.

Then just make a pretty:

```
drush fu my_feature
```

and then we have a taxonomy fields changed continuously integration.